# Deploying a Node.js app using Heroku - start script

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, mean-stack, web-deployment

I'm quite puzzled as to why my app is crashing when deployed to Heroku.

The error is

```
Failed at the ev@1.0.0 start script.
```

Where my start script is

```
"start": "node app.js"
```

because app.js is where it is all initialised (in the same place as package.json, of course).

My app works perfectly fine locally, i.e. it starts app.js and successfully runs, so what could be causing this issue remotely?

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information to help you unfortunately

Comment: What should I include? The app.js is very long so I didn't think I should add that

Answer (score 1):

You must sure that you write  "start": "node app.js"  inside the script. Because Heroku Read this Scripts to start the nodejs Server i.e

```
"scripts": {
"start":"node app.js" 
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  }
```